# How to query based on min and max dates in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have to query based on min and max dates in database ,but the below query seems to be incorrect,how can i achieve result based on min and max dates.

```
select s.new_state as State,d.new_dist as District,b.ifBook as Book,sum(a.amt) as Amount
from 
   mtrans a 
JOIN 
   isbn b 
on 
   b.isbnd=a.isbn 
and 
   a.orgdate 
between 
   min(a.orgdate) and max(a.orgdate) 
JOIN 
   user c 
on 
   a.excd=c.mtrans 
JOIN 
   state_mapping s 
on 
   b.state=s.org_state 
JOIN 
   dist_mapping d 
on 
   b.dist=d.org_dist 
where  
   TRIM(b.ifBook) <> '' 
and 
   b.ifBook IS NOT NULL 
and 
   b.ifBook not like '%TRAVAN%' 
and 
   TRIM(d.new_dist) <> '' 
and 
   d.new_dist IS NOT NULL 
group by 
   b.ifBook,d.new_dist,s.new_state
```

Comment: Can you break that query into multiple lines for better readability?

Comment: Why do you want `a.orgdate between min(a.orgdate) and max(a.orgdate)` ? `a.orgdate` will always be between `min(a.orgdate) and max(a.orgdate)`