# php to java socket program

Tags: java, php, sockets

I have a php program which generates data in xls format.
I have to read each row and format the row in specific format and same the formatted message in txt format and then use a java program to post it to another application (this java does by socket programming).

Since i am new to socket programming how should i proceed
1)How should i reformat the message?
2)then connect to java socket program to post the text file?
3)How do i read the response from java socket program to text file?
4)Reformat the message back from txt to excel format?

Comment: You have asked 12 questions in the past but you have not accepted any answers.If any answer is useful then accept those

Comment: since i am new to the forum,i didnt know that, will do that surely

Comment: you will find an arrow when you click on that then it will be highlighted in green

Comment: see this [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and see this link How Op accepted my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258833/i-want-to-parse-string-into-java-date-object/20258918#20258918

Comment: for few questions the answer is in the comment how can i mark it as answer? for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19970375/how-to-query-based-on-min-and-max-dates-in-mysql    the answer is the comment itself

Comment: If the answer is in given in answer section then you can accept that but if the answer is in comment then you can not accept that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*1)How should i reformat the message?*  This depends on your requirement.

2)then connect to java socket program to post the text file? Read thoroughly the following links [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) and [javaworld](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-1996/jw-12-sockets.html)

*then use a java program to post it to another application (this java does by socket programming).* [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555668/java-send-file-using-sockets) may be useful